# Displaying the actual parameter list of the function during execution

Tags: r, function-call

I am trying to display the actual values of the parameters that were supplied when the function was called. `match.call' does something along the lines I want but it does not evaluate variables. For example

```
foo <- function(x) match.call()
foo(2)
```

prints

```
foo(x = 2)
```

and I am happy with that. However:

```
xxx <- 2
foo(xxx)
```

will print

```
foo(x = xxx)
```

instead of `foo(x = 2)` as I would like to have it.

I have tried various combinations of `substitute`, `eval`, and company, but was not succesful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but probably you can do it by:

```
x<-"a"
y<-mean
z<-1
foo <- function(x,y,z) {
  do.call("call", 
          c(list(as.character(match.call()[[1]])),
            lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1],eval)))
}
foo(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Oooh, tricky! It solves the problem that using `eval` on `match.call()` directly will just call the function again. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a function expand.call() that does what you want (I think...) a while ago. Actually, it does a little more:

```
#' Return a call in which all of the arguments which were supplied
#' or have presets are specified by their full names and supplied
#' or default values.
#'  
#' @param definition a function. See \code{\link[base]{match.call}}.
#' @param call an unevaluated call to the function specified by definition.
#'  See \code{\link[base]{match.call}}.
#' @param expand.dots logical. Should arguments matching ... in the call be 
#'  included or left as a ... argument? See \code{\link[base]{match.call}}.
#' @param doEval logical, defaults to TRUE. Should function arguments be 
#'  evaluated in the returned call or not?
#'
#' @return An object of class call. 
#' @author fabians
#' @seealso \code{\link[base]{match.call}}
expand.call <- function(definition=NULL,
         call=sys.call(sys.parent(1)),
         expand.dots = TRUE,
         doEval=TRUE)
{

    safeDeparse <- function(expr){
        #rm line breaks, whitespace             
        ret <- paste(deparse(expr), collapse="")
        return(gsub("[[:space:]][[:space:]]+", " ", ret))
    }

    call <- .Internal(match.call(definition, call, expand.dots))

    #supplied args:
    ans <- as.list(call)
    if(doEval & length(ans) > 1) {
      for(i in 2:length(ans)) ans[[i]] <- eval(ans[[i]])
    }

    #possible args:
    frmls <- formals(safeDeparse(ans[[1]]))
    #remove formal args with no presets:
    frmls <- frmls[!sapply(frmls, is.symbol)]

    add <- which(!(names(frmls) %in% names(ans)))
    return(as.call(c(ans, frmls[add])))
}
```

You would normally use this as a substitute for match.call() if you need to preserve some some more info about the call or have it formatted more nicely, like:

```
foo <- function(x, bar="bar", gnurp=10, ...) {
    call <- expand.call(...)
    return(call)
}   

> foo(2)
foo(x = 2, bar = "bar", gnurp = 10)

> xxx <- 2
> foo(xxx)
foo(x = 2, bar = "bar", gnurp = 10)

> foo(xxx, b="bbbb")
foo(x = 2, bar = "bbbb", gnurp = 10)

> foo(xxx, b="bbbb", doEval=FALSE)
foo(x = xxx, bar = "bbbb", doEval = FALSE, gnurp = 10)
```

Maybe you can use it to solve your problem.

Comment: This is a great function! I think the formal argument `eval` is missing, though. If I might add a suggestion: perhaps you would consider naming that argument `doEval` so as not to cause confusion with the function `eval`.

Comment: Thanks, @BenBarnes. I made the changes you suggested.

Comment: Using apply for the eval messes up the search path. If you have defined a variable c, then it will be evaluated to the c primitive function. Better use a for loop.

Comment: @ThomasP85 thanks, I changed it the way you suggested.